# Is it possible to limit the length of a conditional list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am doing a conditional list comprehension e.g. `newlist = [x for x in list if x % 2 == 0]`. I want to limit the length of the *resulting* list to a specific number.

**Is this possible without first comprehending the entire list and then slicing it?**

I imagine something that has the functionality of:

```
limit = 10
newlist = []

for x in list:

    if len(newlist) > limit:
        break 

    if x % 2 == 0:
        newlist.append(x)
```

Slicing the original list (e.g. `[x for x in list[:25] if x % 2 == 0]` is not possible, as the if condition does not return `True` in any predictable intervals in my specific use case.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: While it is possible, *why do you want to do this*? The solution will include several deeply nested expressions – using a loop is likely plain more readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please don't name any variables `list` as it shadows the built-in `list` constructor. I used `li` as a replacement for the input list here.

```py
import itertools as it

gen = (x for x in li if x % 2 == 0)  # Lazy generator.
result = list(it.islice(gen, 25))
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you are creating a list with the list comprehension you can slice your list directly after it is created.

`[x for x in list[:25] if x % 2 == 0][:limit]`

Comment: That is explicitly not wanted by the question: "Is this possible without first comprehending the entire list and then slicing it?"

Comment: Hey it would seems so. Thats what you get when answering questions very late at night.